# Try / Catch or Error Variable and using either

Tags: powershell

I am wondering if the `Try / Catch` below works or should I use an `IF ($problem)` instead of the `Try/Catch`

```
Try {
    New-Item -Path C:\reports -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable Problem -Force
}
Catch {
    Write-Warning "Problem with C:\Report directory. Unable to create report $Type of $SourceEmail $Flag $DestinationEmail"
}
```

I am checking to see if a directory exists and if not attempt to create the directory.
I am not sure if because I am using `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable Problem` the `try/catch` is not working as intended?

Altenative

```
 New-Item -Path C:\reports -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable Problem -Force
 If ($Problem) {
  Write-Warning "Problem trying to create C:\Reports."
 }
```

Comment: An exception has to be thrown in order for you to catch it. Change `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to `-ErrorAction Stop`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen so the ```SilentlyContinue``` overrides the ```try/catch ``` ?
 Is there any reason to every use  ```SilentlyContinue```  and a error variable ?

Comment: Incidentally, you should expect that to cause an error for most user accounts as writing to the root of the C: drive is not allowed, for security. Please see [#PSTip Working with Special Folders](https://powershellmagazine.com/2013/10/30/pstip-working-with-special-folders/) for ideas on where the data should be saved.

Comment: As @MathiasR.Jessen has mentioned, @dcaz, at the moment when you use `SilentlyContinue` you are just telling PowerShell to carry on as if there was no error, which means the catch block is not invoked. If you want to hit the catch block, the cmdlet in the try block either needs to create a terminating error or you need to tell it to stop with `-ErrorAction Stop` if it creates a non-terminating error. You may want to exit in the catch block too if the rest of the script cannot continue without the `New-Item` command being successful.

Comment: @dcaz Silentlycontinue does not override the try/catch mechanics so much as it tells New-Item not to throw the exception in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am checking to see if a directory exists and if not attempt to create the directory.

[`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item)'s `-Force` switch can be used to create a directory *unless it already exists*; a [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) object describing either the preexisting directory or the newly created directory is returned (note that `-Force` also creates *parent* directories on demand).

Since you're already using `-Force`, this means that only a *true error condition* is reported, such as a lack of permissions.

In the simplest case, you can simply *abort* your script when such an error condition occurs, using `-ErrorAction Stop` to convert the (first) *non-terminating* error that `New-Item` reports to a *script-terminating* one:

```
$targetDir = New-Item -Force -ErrorAction Stop -Path C:\reports -ItemType Directory
```

If an error occurs, it will be printed, and the script will be aborted.

If you want to *capture* errors and perform custom actions, you have two mutually exclusive options:

- Capture the non-terminating error in variable `$Problem`, via `-ErrorVariable Problem`, and act on the value of `$Problem` afterwards; `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` suppresses *display* of the error:<sup>[1]</sup>

```
$targetDir = New-Item -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable Problem -Path C:\reports -ItemType Directory

if ($Problem) { 
  Write-Warning "Problem trying to create C:\Reports: $Problem"
  # Exit here, if needed.
  exit 1
}
```

- Promote the (first) non-terminating error to a script-*terminating* one via `-ErrorAction Stop` and use a `try { ... } catch { ... }` statement to catch it, in whose `catch` block `$_` refers to the error at hand:

```
try {
  $targetDir = New-Item -Force -ErrorAction Stop -Path C:\reports -ItemType Directory
} catch {
  $Problem = $_
  Write-Warning "Problem trying to create C:\Reports: $Problem"
  # Exit here, if needed.
  exit 1
}
```

For a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's surprisingly complex error handling, see [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).

---

<sup>[1] This makes the capturing of the error via `-ErrorVariable` silent; do *not* use `-ErrorAction Ignore`, as that will render `-ErrorVariable` ineffective.</sup>